# Как сделать чтобы видео на фоне подстраивалось под разрешение экрана, но и мотать вниз можно было?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, видео

У меня есть видео на фоне.

```css
#myVideo {
  -moz-background-size: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: -1000;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
    <source src="../mp4/Fon_2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Как сделать чтобы видео подстраивалось под разрешение экрана, но и мотнуть, чтобы видео уходило вверх? Вообщем как на этом сайте https://rpcs3.net/

Comment: Для высоты и ширины можно использовать `100vh` и `100vw` соответственно, что бы занимать всю ширину экрана.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все просто :)

```css
#myVideo {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: У меня видео не во весь widht делается. Только при удалении widht и height все норм, во весь горизонт

Answer (score 0):

в отдельный div оберни его и все, и будет у тебя видео в фоне блока, а не всего backround

а, ну и

```
...
position: fixed;
...
```

тогда не нужен

Ну и вариант номер два, это подключить jQuery и плагин jquery.vide.js
и просто добавляем атрибут data-vide-bg="path/video" к нужному блоку.

```
<div data-vide-bg="/demo/vide/video">
    <div style="padding:200px 10px; font-size:30px; text-align:center; color: #BFE2FF">
        Адаптивное видео для фона
    </div>
</div>
```

вот тут описано: https://atuin.ru/blog/adaptivnoe-video-dlya-fona-bloka/